# Why does redis forcibly demote master to slave?

Tags: redis

Run the container using docker redis:latest, and after about 30 minutes, the master changes to a slave and it is no longer writable.
Also, the slave outputs an error once per second that it cannot find the master.

```
1:M 08 Jul 2022 03:10:55.899 * DB saved on disk
1:M 08 Jul 2022 03:15:56.087 * 100 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
1:M 08 Jul 2022 03:15:56.089 * Background saving started by pid 61
61:C 08 Jul 2022 03:15:56.091 * DB saved on disk
61:C 08 Jul 2022 03:15:56.092 * Fork CoW for RDB: current 0 MB, peak 0 MB, average 0 MB
1:M 08 Jul 2022 03:15:56.189 * Background saving terminated with success
1:S 08 Jul 2022 03:20:12.258 * Before turning into a replica, using my own master parameters to synthesize a cached master: I may be able to synchronize with the new master with just a partial transfer.
1:S 08 Jul 2022 03:20:12.258 * Connecting to MASTER 178.20.40.200:8886
1:S 08 Jul 2022 03:20:12.258 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
1:S 08 Jul 2022 03:20:12.259 * REPLICAOF 178.20.40.200:8886 enabled (user request from 'id=39 addr=95.182.123.66:36904 laddr=172.31.9.234:6379 fd=11 name= age=1 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=47 qbuf-free=20427 argv-mem=24 multi-mem=0 rbs=1024 rbp=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 tot-mem=22320 events=r cmd=slaveof user=default redir=-1 resp=2')
1:S 08 Jul 2022 03:20:12.524 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
1:S 08 Jul 2022 03:20:12.791 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
1:S 08 Jul 2022 03:20:13.335 * Trying a partial resynchronization (request 6743ff015583c86f3ac7a4305026c42991a1ca18:1).
1:S 08 Jul 2022 03:20:13.603 * Full resync from master: ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ:1
1:S 08 Jul 2022 03:20:13.603 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: receiving 54976 bytes from master to disk
1:S 08 Jul 2022 03:20:14.138 * Discarding previously cached master state.
1:S 08 Jul 2022 03:20:14.138 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Flushing old data
1:S 08 Jul 2022 03:20:14.139 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Loading DB in memory
1:S 08 Jul 2022 03:20:14.140 # Wrong signature trying to load DB from file
1:S 08 Jul 2022 03:20:14.140 # Failed trying to load the MASTER synchronization DB from disk: Invalid argument
1:S 08 Jul 2022 03:20:14.140 * Reconnecting to MASTER 178.20.40.200:8886 after failure
1:S 08 Jul 2022 03:20:14.140 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started

...

1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:50.010 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:50.298 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:50.587 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:50.587 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:51.013 * Connecting to MASTER 178.20.40.200:8886
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:51.014 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:51.294 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:51.581 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:51.581 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:52.017 * Connecting to MASTER 178.20.40.200:8886
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:52.017 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:52.297 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:52.578 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:52.578 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:53.021 * Connecting to MASTER 178.20.40.200:8886
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:53.021 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:53.308 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:53.594 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:53.594 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:54.025 * Connecting to MASTER 178.20.40.200:8886
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:54.025 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:54.316 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:54.608 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:54.608 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:55.028 * Connecting to MASTER 178.20.40.200:8886
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:55.028 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:55.309 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:55.588 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:55.588 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:56.031 * Connecting to MASTER 178.20.40.200:8886
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:56.031 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:56.311 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:56.592 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:56.592 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:57.035 * Connecting to MASTER 178.20.40.200:8886
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:57.035 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:57.321 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
1:S 08 Jul 2022 05:09:57.610 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
...
```

```
SLAVEOF NO ONE
config set slave-read-only no
```

If I force the slave to be writable with the above command and try to write, all data will be flushed after about 5 seconds.
I don't want to turn master into slave.
I am getting this error on clean ec2 amazon linux.
I don't know what's causing this error because I also have enough memory.

Why does redis forcibly demote master to slave?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I got same issue

Comment: @MasterLuV It's not exact, but it seems to be an out-of-memory. I got about 4gb as swap, so this bug didn't happen anymore.